# DocuSign Return Payload Missing Custom Fields

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I'm working on building a SpringCM workflow that uses DocuSign for sending and recieving electronic signatures. Durring our testing and build we were pointed to a Test/Trial DocuSign Account.

We had created a process that after the Document was signed it looked for the 'Custom Fields' inside of the returned payload to grab the 'Effective Date'. Nothing special was set up in our trial/demo account to accomidate this.

Now that we are pointed to the customers production account inside of DocuSign we are no longer recieving the 'Custom Fields' in the payload recieved from DocuSign.

Old Payload in Trial account **WITH** custom fields:

```
<HistoryEvent>
  <Email>XXXXXXX@email.com</Email>
  <Status>Signed</Status>
  <DelegatedTo />
  <UpdatedDate>2018-09-25T21:20:48.847Z</UpdatedDate>
  <Comments />
  <CustomFields>
    <CustomField>
      <Name>Signature 1_SignHere_0146017e-d0c8-4a85-b890-51c79e66a8a3</Name>
    </CustomField>
  </CustomFields>
</HistoryEvent>
```

New payload in production account **WITHOUT** custom fields:

```
   <HistoryEvent>
      <Email>xxxxxxx@email.com</Email>
      <Status>Signed</Status>
      <DelegatedTo />
      <UpdatedDate>2018-10-10T14:46:15.507Z</UpdatedDate>
      <Comments />
      <CustomFields />
    </HistoryEvent>
```

Question: Is there a setting or something inside of DocuSign that is causing me to NOT get the 'Custom Fields' in this new DocuSign environment?

Any suggestions on why I am not getting the data I'm expecting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Connect to receive this payload?

There is a setting in the connect configuration to under "Include:" for Document Fields. That should push the custom fields through in the payload.

[image]

Comment: Hey Rickey, thanks for the response. Although I feel like we're close, I'm not sure waht Connect is. I'm building a SpringCM workflow that has a 'Docusign Connector' built into it. This may suggset that there is something I need to do on the SpringCM side to get the Document fields. What is this 'Connect' you are referencing above? Is this somewhere inside of DocuSign or is this a different application? Thanks

Comment: This has to do with the webhook setup. If you open the admin area it will have a connect section listed in the left menu. This is where you create configs for various integrations a specific DocuSign has. The settings Rickey posted a screenshot of are there.